# How to fix run-time error 1004 Method Range of object global failed

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to run this code and it has worked before on other projects so I do not understand why it is not working on this code.

I have tried looking to see if I have  missed stuff from previous code but I don't think I am

```
    Sub DepolPotential()
    DataSheet.Activate
    Dim DepolPotential As Range
    Dim Count1 As Range
    Dim Cells1 As Range
    Dim Count2 As Range
    Set Cells1 = Range("N2", Range("N2").End(xlDown))
    Set Cells2 = Range("N2", Range("N2").End(xlDown))
    Set Count2 = Range("N2")

    Do
    Set Cells1 = Range(Count2, Range("N2").End(xlDown))
    Set Count1 = Count2
    For Each Count1 In Cells1
      If Count2 Is Nothing Then
        Exit Do
      End If
      If Count1.Value < 1 And Count1.Offset(3, 0).Value < 1 Then
        Set DepolPotential = Count1.Offset(0, -12)
         Count1.Offset(0, 20).Value = DepolPotential.Value
         Exit For
      End If
    Next Count1
    Dim InstOn As Range
      If Count1 Is Nothing Then
        Exit Do
      End If
   Set Cells2 = Range(Count1, Range("N2").End(xlDown))
   For Each Count2 In Cells2
    If Count2.Value > 1 And Count1.Offset(3, 0).Value > 1 Then
      Set InstOn = Count2.Offset(0, -12)
      Count2.Offset(0, 21).Value = InstOn.Value
      Count2.Offset(1, 22).Value = InstOn.Offset(1, 0).Value
      Set Count2 = Count2.Offset(2, 0)
      Exit For
    End If
   Next Count2
   Loop Until Count1 Is Nothing
```

I am getting the error on line

```
Set Cells1 = Range(Count2, Range("N2").End(xlDown))
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error in previous codes this did not give me an error.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting the error on the "DataSheet.Activate" line? DataSheet does not appear to be defined. Try replacing it with `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Activate` where _SheetName_ is the name of your worksheet.

Comment: @FrankH. Presumably `DataSheet` is the *code name* of a workshet that exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time -- and if that's the case, it's a million times safer than dereferencing that worksheet by name off whatever workbook is currently active.

Comment: No that did not fix it

Comment: @MathieuGuindon yes of course, but I only suggested using the explicit sheet name to eliminate the possibility of the error being caused by what appears to be an undefined object in the provided code.

Comment: Look, we're trying to help.

Comment: I very much appreciate it I just don't  think it is how I am referencing my data sheets as I have used this exact  code on other projects before

Comment: I've probably answered this error 1004 question well over 100 times, and pretty much *every single time*, it was because of implicit ActiveSheet references. So much so, I wrote a code inspection in a VBIDE add-in to locate these buggers. Now, I'm trying to make sense of this code, and it's extremely difficult for several reasons - variable names with a number suffix changing meaning/purpose over the course of execution being the chief reason. Poor indentation with nested loop structures is another. `.Offset` is making things even more mind-blowingly hard to track what `Count2` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what your data looks like, but the outer loop breaks on the second iteration with an empty `DataSheet`, with the error you describe. That's a good thing, because `cells1.Address` is `$N$2:$N$1048576` on an empty sheet... but it doesn't matter, because the first empty cell meets the condition and exits the first inner loop.

But that's merely a symptom, not the real problem.

The second loop is iterating the exact same range as the first loop, but this time none of the empty cells meets the condition, and the loop goes on to iterate every single agonizing row on the worksheet.

And when that loop exits, the `count2` loop variable reference is `Nothing` - that's why the 2nd iteration explodes: `[_Global|Worksheet].Range` accepts several different ways to specify a range of cells, but `Nothing` is an illegal argument to give it; it raises an error, and execution abruptly stops.

What's happening? The VBA language specifications are relevant here:

> When the `<for-each-statement>` has finished executing, the value of `<bound-variable-expression>` is the data value of the last element in `<collection>`.
>
> <sup><sub>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/b132463a-fd25-4143-8fc7-a443930e0651</sub></sup>

It seems as per specs, both `count1` and `count2` should have a valid object reference when the loops exit. However it seems Microsoft's implementation of the VBA language specifications work differently. Here's a minimal repro example:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection
    c.Add New Collection 'any object will do
    Dim o As Object
    For Each o In c
        'Exit For
    Next
    Debug.Print o Is Nothing
End Sub
```

Run this code once with `Exit For` commented-out, then un-comment the statement and run it again. The "bound variable" of a `For Each` loop that is iterating an object collection will be `Nothing` **if the loop runs to completion**.

That means if the first inner loop ran to completion, you would be having the same error here:

> ```
>   Set Cells2 = Range(Count1, Range("N2").End(xlDown))
> ```

Because `Count1` would be `Nothing` then. On an empty sheet, `Count1` is pointing to `$N$2` at this point, so `Cells2` gets to be `$N$2:$N$1048576`.

**When the second inner loop runs to completion**, `Count2` is `Nothing`, and since the loop condition is only looking at `Count1`...

> ```
>  Loop Until Count1 Is Nothing
> ```

...the second iteration of the outer loop blows up when `Count2` is passed as an argument to `_Global.Range`, which fails with error 1004:

> ```
>   Set Cells1 = Range(Count2, Range("N2").End(xlDown))
> ```

I suppose a band-aid solution could be to [verify whether `Count2 Is Nothing` before using it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57502928/1188513), although that's exactly the same as changing the exit condition to check for both `Count1` and `Count2`:

```
Loop Until Count1 Is Nothing Or Count2 Is Nothing
```

...and I don't think that's the right solution. In fact I'm not sure it's *a* solution.

I can't be 100% sure because I haven't spent too much time trying to work out how `Count2` not being `Nothing` affects the outer loop (plus I didn't have any data to toy with), but I think this *might* just happen to be doing the same thing:

```
Dim interestingCells As Range
Set interestingCells = DataSheet.Range("N2:N" & DataSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In interestingCells
    If cell.Value < 1 And cell.Offset(3).Value < 1 Then
        cell.Offset(0, 20).Value = cell.Offset(0, -12).Value
    ElseIf cell.Value > 1 And cell.Offset(3).Value > 1 Then
        cell.Offset(0, 21).Value = cell.Offset(0, -12).Value
        cell.Offset(1, 22).Value = cell.Offset(1).Value
    End If
Next
```

I honestly think the *real* solution is to take a step back and re-assess exactly what this loop means to be doing, scrap the old code, and rewrite it from scratch. Anything else would add complexity to an already incredibly hard-to-follow piece of code. Other than the recycled `For Each` loop variables, the *row* offsets are particularly confusing: a comment detailing *why* the next row needs to be affected would be in order - note that such logic probably requires the data to be sorted in a particular way... which might be a bad assumption to make, i.e. a disastrous bug waiting to show its ugly head. Also note that if the iterated range happens to span the entire column, then `cell.Offset(n)` will fail for any positive value of `n` when `cell` is in the very last row, and for any value of `n` greater than the number of rows left under it if it's *near* the very last row on the worksheet.

Also note the `.End(xlUp)` logic to get the last row/cell with data: with that, an empty sheet will not run a single iteration.

Lastly, note the explicitly qualified `Range` call, so that it resolves to `DataSheet.Range` rather than `_Global.Range` - this is one of the very few times I've seen error 1004 thrown by `_Global.Range` where the root of the issue wasn't the use of unqualified `Range` calls implicitly referring to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is.

Answer (score 0):

Launched your code.
On line

```
Set Cells1 = Range (Count2, Range ('N2'). End (xlDown))
```

Count2 became Nothing

As a solution, move the code

```
If Count2 Is Nothing Then
  Exit do
End if
```

Before the line

```
Set Cells1 = Range (Count2, Range ('N2'). End (xlDown))
```

Answer (score 0):

I Had exactly the same problem in my VBA project.
after long searching and experience many failures, I decided to write my Ranges with full address, include workbook & worksheets, for example:

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("myRange").Cells(1,1).Value

After applying this decision, my codes never experienced "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed" again since yet.
Please check this for your codes and your feedback here.
Thank you.